# Given a divergent series, which alterations are convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

For a sequence $a_n \gt 0$ I'm given that $\sum a_n$ diverges.
Let $s_n = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$

It's not immediately obvious, but $\sum \frac{a_n}{s_n^2}$ converges, while $\sum \frac{a_n}{s_n}$ does not.

Knowing these facts, however, can I somehow show divergence or convergence of the series:
$\sum \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ and $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+n^2a_n}$?

Comment: I suspect that the first series always diverges and I know that the second one always converges by comparison to $1/n^2$

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269583/if-sum-limits-n-1-inftya-n-diverges-does-sum-limits-n-1-infty/269586#269586).